# Is this rollback worthy?

Tags: discussion, rollbacks

I'm looking at a question, and I thought it was vandalized because the question in the title and the question in the body are so dissimilar: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25155513/revisions.

When I went to history, I see that the user did it himself:

[image]

**Questions**:

1. Is a rollback appropriate given the author did this?
2. <strike>If a rollback is in order, then how do I do it since revision 3 does not have a rollback link?</strike>
3. If a rollback is not in order, then what is appropriate?

Comment: There is no rollback button for revision 3 since it is the *current* revision. You want to rollback to a previous revision, and that's where you find the relevant rollback button.

Comment: It was edited from one bad question into another bad question. The suggested edit should never have been approved as it was too minor to salvage the post, it never should have been answered in the form it was written in, and it's not worth the time of Meta to consider it, really.

Comment: Account needs to be nuked from orbit.

Answer (score 7):

**If the user has another question, they should ask another question.**

This is usually a way to escape a question ban and is highly discouraged, so:

Yes, roll it back to revision 2.  If the edit changes the question body radically (and not even the question title or tags for that matter...), then it can do the following:

- invalidate answers currently being written
- invalidate already submitted answers
- confuse users who are searching and find a completely different question in the actual body

If the user continues trying to change it, raise a moderator attention flag and the moderator may revert new edit along with lock the post.

---

To address your questions specifically:

> Is a rollback appropriate given the author did this?

Yes.

> If a rollback is in order, then how do I do it since revision 3 does not have a rollback link?

There is a rollback button on revision 2 since your are rolling it back *to* revision 2.

> If a rollback is not in order, then what is appropriate?

Well, a rollback is appropriate.

Comment: Thanks @Anonymous. I don't ever recall performing a rollback, so please forgive my ignorance. Fortunately, its kept me out of a number of wars ;)

Comment: No problem. It's always better to get a second opinion than to just go on impulse if you're unsure.